# Python version not found when I run python--version via powershell command window nor python shell itself. How do i fix this?

Tags: python

PS C:\Users\LENOVO> python--version
python--version : The term 'python--version' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1

- python--version
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python--version:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you trying to do ```python --version```?

Comment: If the comment above is not clear, you are missing a space.

Comment: are you able to run the 'python' command? Looks like you didn't add python to path.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think should happen when you run `python--version`, and *what exactly led you to that conclusion*? Are you familiar with using the command line in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried it with space in between?
`python --version`

Comment: got it right,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
python --version
```

If that doesn't work, it means that you didn't add python to path.